# Prometheus New Registry enable HTTP Metrics

Tags: go, prometheus

I am using:

```
var registry = prometheus.NewRegistry()
```

I know I can do for some goroutine (etc.) related metrics:

```
registry.MustRegistry(collectors.NewGoCollector());
```

But, I cannot see http metrics which I see when using default registry, like:

```
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="200"} 1
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="500"} 0
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="503"} 0
```

How to bring these metrics?

Also, I cannot see `http_requests_total` irrespective of the registry I use. Is there a way to automatically expose it (instead of defining it)?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to register your custom defined metric like `http_requests_total` (in this case).

This should solve your problem :

`registry.MustRegistry(promHttpRequestTotal)

Here `promHttpRequestTotal` is the variable in which your metric `http_requests_total` is defined.